# Django 5.0.2: TypeError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken

Tags: django, django-views

Why is this not working?
I get the error "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."
What can I do to solve this?

```
class LogbookLastViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LogbookSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filterset_fields = ['organizationID']
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Logbook.objects.filter(organizationID='1111').order_by('-created')[:10]
        return queryset
```

I need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM logbook WHERE organizationID='1111' ORDER_BY created LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the `filterset_fields`. Such filtering will happen *after* the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself), but since you slice in the `get_queryset`, additional filtering is not possible.

You can do the slicing in the `.paginate_queryset(…)` instead:

```
class LogbookLastViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LogbookSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filterset_fields = ['organizationID']
    queryset = Logbook.objects.all()

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
        return queryset[:10]
```

Comment: Thankyou, the paginate_query didn´t work for me, when doing an quick test. 
But your explaination helped me a lot. If I remove the "filterset_fields" it is working for me.

Comment: @MatrixClient: did you remove the `get_queryset`?

Comment: no, I just removed "filterset_fields = ['organizationID']"

Comment: @MatrixClient: but likely the problem can also be tackled by removing `get_queryset`, use `queryset = ...` instead, let the `filterset_fields` do their job, and then paginate the result with `[:10]`.

Comment: You are absoluty right. Perfect solution.